# wordpress: force record to top before the rest

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-order-by, case-when

We have a wordpress site and we want, on the archives page for a custom post type, to force a certain post to the top all the time.

We are using 'pre_get_posts' in functions.php to edit the sql.

Directly in MySQL we can use:
... ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 7075 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

But we cant get that 'order by' clause called from functions.php
(We are dumping the sql statement to the page to see how its processed)

$query->set( 'orderby', '  CASE WHEN ID = 7075 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  ' );
(this gets changed to '...ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC')

$query->set( 'orderby', ' (ID = 7075) ' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
(this gets ignored and the default is used '... ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC ')

$query->set( 'orderby', array(  'CASE WHEN wp_posts.ID = 7075  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END' => 'ASC') );
(no order by clause at all with this one)

Has anyone managed to do this before?
We'd like to not write custom sql for the page.
Any help appreciated :)

V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do two queries, one that just outputs the post you want at the top and one that outputs all posts except the one at the top.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy :) i was so far down the rabbit hole i wasnt looking left - thank you,